# How can I add an attribute to a queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, attributes, django-queryset

I've got a Django 2.2.28 legacy application running under Python 3.7.7. I've got a queryset I'd like to add data to that's not from the database, but generated by Python. So something like this:

```
for item in queryset.iterator():
    item.new_property = python_generated_property_value()
```

I want this `new_property` to be available in a template. Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make a method on your model's class?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a dictionary, and pass data in a template with it

```
new_dict = {}
for item in queryset.iterator():
    new_dict["item_property"] = python_generated_property_value()
```

this will give you a dictionary in a same order as it is in your queryset, and you could "for loop" this dict in parallel with your queryset in a template

Comment: That's pretty good, I'm going to give that a try. I need to figure out how to add `new_dict` to the template context. :) 
Though I've worked with Python a long time, I'm kind of a noob at Django.